# xlwings: make cell bold

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I [have seen](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/559) that stylistic requests are to be implemented in xlwings.

Is there a workaround to make the content of a cell bold?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since xlwings 0.23.0, this is now available natively:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
wb.sheets[0].range('A1').font.bold = True
```

For xlwings < 0.23.0, you can work around it like this:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
wb.sheets[0].range('A1').api.Font.Bold = True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there a guide to these features? For instance if I want the cell to be formatted as currency?

Comment: Everything that's built in you can find here: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html and how to get around missing features you can find here: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
wb = xw.Book()
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
sht.range('A1').value = 'Foo 1'
sht.range('A1').api.font_object.font_style.set('bold')
```

Comment: This was the workaround on macOS, but that's now not required anymore since 0.23.0